# How can I generate oauthSignature?

Tags: reactjs, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I want to use twitter API. So I need some GET and POST methods. I have consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token and Token Secret keys but I want to generate oauth_nonce and oauth_timestamp according to HMAC-SHA1 signature method. I found a source about this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-signature). However I didn't understand because here the key is given by me. Is there a way to do that, so can I generate myself with a short block of code?

Answer (score 0):

In my project's .NET implementation of OAuth, we did it this way:

```
public virtual string GenerateTimeStamp()
{
    // Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
}

public virtual string GenerateNonce()
{
    return (new Guid()).ToString().Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: I understand that the asker is not working in .NET, but I believe that providing the code sample above will allow the asker to craft their own solution in their chosen language(s).